# Refreshing a collection of partials with infowindows

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

Currently i am working with Gmaps4Rails and have my infowindows refreshing with my collection of partials. However, when my infowindows are refreshed, the collection of partials will be put in one infowindow. I need a way to connect the partials to each marker in Gmaps4Rails. Ultimately, there will be one partial refreshing for each marker but currently am having all 5 partials being rendered in one infowindow when the refresh function is called.

Here is my controller action

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController


def index
    @events = Event.all
    @lat_lng ||= cookies[:lat_lng] ? cookies[:lat_lng].split("|") : nil
    @locations= Event.where( "date(start) = ?", Date.today).all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|
      marker.lat location.latitude
      marker.lng location.longitude
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "info", :locals => { :event => location })
      marker.picture({
        "url" => "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
        "width" => 32,
        "height" => 37
      })
    end
  end
    def refresh

    @lat_lng ||= cookies[:lat_lng] ? cookies[:lat_lng].split("|") : nil
    @locations= Event.where( "start = ?", Date.today).all
    render :partial => 'welcome/info/', :collection => @locations, :as => :event

   end
end
end
```

My partial with the local variable at the top--This is my welcome/info partial.

```
.event-data{id: event.id}
  .row
    .small-3.columns.mright
      .avatar
        %img.avatar{:src => event.user.avatar(:thumb), class: 'th'}
    .small-6.columns.mleft.left-border
      .truckname
        %strong
        = event.user.truckname
      .address
        = event.address
      .times  
        = event.start.strftime('%I:%M')
        to
        = event.end.strftime('%I:%M') 

    .small-2.columns.left-border
      .distance
        =number_with_precision(event.distance_to(cookies[:lat_lng].split("|")), precision: 2)
        %br
        miles away
```

Here is my javascript to call the refresh with the controller action.

```
:javascript

    var styles = [
      {
        featureType: 'landscape',
        elementType: 'all',
        stylers: [
          { hue: '#f9f4f0' },
          { saturation: 22 },
          { lightness: 63 },
          { visibility: 'on' }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'all',
        stylers: [
          { hue: '#b9ded6' },
          { saturation: -64 },
          { lightness: 44 },
          { visibility: 'on' }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'all',
        stylers: [
          { hue: '#bccecb' },
          { saturation: -66 },
          { lightness: 5 },
          { visibility: 'on' }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: 'poi',
        elementType: 'all',
        stylers: [
          { hue: '#bccecb' },
          { saturation: -64 },
          { lightness: -1 },
          { visibility: 'on' }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: 'administrative',
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [
          { hue: '#d8444c' },
          { saturation: 65 },
          { lightness: 10 },
          { visibility: 'on' }
        ]
      }
    ];

  var marker;
  var updatedmarkers;
  var truckmarkers;
  var geolocatedmarker;
  var lat;
  var lng;
  var cookie_val;

  function setCoords(position){
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
  };

  function setGeoCookie() {
    cookie_val = lat + "|" + lng;
    document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
  }

  function displayOnMap(position){
    geolocatedmarker = handler.addMarker({
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude,
      infowindow: 'Current Position',
      picture: {
      "url": "http://www.galbraithmt.com/guide/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bluedot.png",
      "width":  36,
      "height": 36,
      },
    });
    handler.map.centerOn(geolocatedmarker);
    handler.getMap().setZoom(17);
    handler.getMap().setOptions({ scrollwheel: false })
    truckmarkers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @hash.to_json});
  };

  var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null }, builders: { Marker:   InfoBoxBuilder} });
  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'geolocation'}, provider: {styles: styles} }, function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation)
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCoords);
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
  });

  $('#geocodeID').click(function(){
    var user_input = $('input[name="inputbox"]').val();
    geocodeAddress(user_input);
  });

  function geocodeAddress(input){
    //var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    address = input;

    geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status)
    {
        if ( marker != null ){
          handler.removeMarker(marker);
        }
        marker = handler.addMarker({
          lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
          lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
          infowindow: 'Destination You Selected',
          picture: {
                        "url": "http://www.galbraithmt.com/guide/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bluedot.png",
                        "width":  36,
                        "height": 36
                    },
        });
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        setGeoCookie();
        handler.map.centerOn(marker);
        handler.removeMarker(geolocatedmarker);

      });
    $(document).ready(
          function() {
            setInterval(function() {

              $('.event-data').load('/welcome/refresh/');
          }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

Comment: how do you refresh markers?

Comment: I am sorry about that here is the rest of my javascript. I have this document.ready with the reload being called once the click function is activated with #geocodeID. This function will geocode the address the user puts in. This is why i need my partials refreshed because the distance in the partials within the infowindows will change to events once the user puts a new address in.

Comment: I'm sorry but why do you use `.load`? You have no control this way, you'd rather make an ajax request to get the updated data and update the view.

Comment: so far my partials are being refreshed with the correct distance in them when i am using load. I would rather not switch to ajax if i have this working properly. I just need to know how i can change from rendering a collection to a specific event for that infowindow.

Comment: what did you put in `@hash`?

Comment: There is my index action implementing the @hash in my controller and the partials are being rendered based on the infowindow matching the marker with the location's infowindow. This is sort of a way to loop through the markers however, i dont want to buildmarkers on the refresh action.